# makeAllSearchableUsing doesn't work to eagerload relation with elasticsearch

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch, laravel-scout

I have the following code in my Laravel model:

```php
public function toSearchableArray() {
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
    ];
}

public function mappableAs(): array {
    return [
        'name' => 'text',
        'description' => 'text',
    ];
}

public function makeAllSearchableUsing($query) {
    return $query->with('users');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users');
}
```

I am using [Explorer](https://jeroen-g.github.io/Explorer/) with Laravel Scout and I have both flushed and imported the data.

When I run the query `Model::search('fish')->field('name')->get()`, the output only contains this data:

```
id: 1,
name: "Ea nemo fish unde esse",
description: "Tempore nihil cumque eum quo"
```

However, I expect to get the users relation data which looks like this:

```
users: {
  {id: 1, name: 'User1'},
  {id: 2, name: 'User2'},
}
```

or add the relation of `$query->withCount('users');` and sort by it.

What is causing this problem?

This is my model of User

```
public function toSearchableArray(): array {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email' => $this->email,
        ];
    }

    public function mappableAs(): array {
        return [
            'id' => 'integer',
            'name' => 'text',
            'email' => 'text',
        ];
    }

public function models($owner = true) {
     return $this->hasMany(Model::class);
}
```

and my `explorer.php` has

```
'indexes' => [
        Model::class,
        User::class,
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the `users` relationship in the `toSearchableArray` method:

```
public function toSearchableArray() {
    return [
        'name' => $this->name,
        'description' => $this->description,
        'users' => $this->users,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get users count? I noticed that I don't even need `makeAllSearchableUsing` with `'users' => $this->users,` but I wonder if I can get the count too, I tried ''users_count' => $this->users()->count(),` and `'users_count' => count($this->users)`but it doesn't import